# Give an example to show that integration formula is not necessarily true if f has a pole at a which is not simple

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm working on the following past paper question:

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the punctured disc
$$
B_r^{\prime}(a)=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0<|z-a|<r\} .
$$
Suppose that $0 \leqslant \alpha<\beta \leqslant 2 \pi$ and for $0<\epsilon<r$ let
$$
\gamma_\epsilon:[\alpha, \beta] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}
$$
be the path in $B_r^{\prime}(a)$ defined by $\gamma_\epsilon(t)=a+\epsilon \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} t}$ for $t \in[\alpha, \beta]$. Prove that if $f$ has a simple pole at $a$ then
$$
\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} f(z) \mathrm{d} z \rightarrow \mathrm{i}(\beta-\alpha) \operatorname{res}(f ; a)
$$
as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. **Give an example to show that this is not necessarily true if $f$ has a pole at $a$ which is not simple**.

I tried using $ f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{2}} $ which has a double pole at $ z=0 $

Parameterise as $ z=\varepsilon e^{i t} \Rightarrow z^{\prime}(t)=i \varepsilon e^{\text {it }} $

\begin{array}{l}
\Rightarrow \int_{r \varepsilon} f(z) d z=-\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{\varepsilon^{2} e^{2 i t}} i \varepsilon e^{i t} d t \\
\quad=-\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} e^{-i t} d t=-\frac{2}{\varepsilon} \rightarrow \infty \text { as } \varepsilon \rightarrow 0
\end{array}

$ \operatorname{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{2}}=0 $ so by formula,
$ \int f(z) d z \rightarrow \pi i \times 0=0 $
so example when formula doesn't hold for non-simple poles.

I'm not sure if this is correct, please can someone verify? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your counter-example is correct. More generally, you can show that if you have a pole of higher order, the integral in question will diverge to infinity in module.
Morally, this will be true because of the following: write $f(z)=(z-a)^{-n}g(z)$ with $g$ holomorphic at $a$. Then as $g$ will be continuous at $a$, in a small enough neighborhood, it only takes on values close to $g(a)$. This means that the integral will behave as the integral of $g(a) (z-a)^{-n}$ which diverges for $n>1$

Comment: Isn't it $g(a)(z-a)^{-n}$ at the end of your answer, rather than $g(a)(z-a)^n$?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni you are right, edited. Thanks